# Signal Processing

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, signal-processing

[image: List plot of data]

The image above is the list plot of discrete data I'm working on. Please I need help on how to zero out all the high amplitudes signal from the data. That is all the data in areas circled, I want to make the zeros. The data has Dimensions {24,1400}. That is 24 traces versus  1400 samples. For example, the 3rd and 11th samples in the list below, I want to make them zero, irrespective of their signs(either +ve or -ve). And repeat the same for the whole 24 traces. In other word, I need a code that will search for certain range of values in the list and make them zero.

{{0.098952, 0.099761, 80, 0.18767, 0.06777, -0.20674, -0.14114, 
  0.091522, -0.040536, -0.37627, -60, -0.22996, -0.35529}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {{0.098952, 0.099761, 80, 0.18767, 0.06777, -0.20674, -0.14114, 
    0.091522, -0.040536, -0.37627, -60, -0.22996, -0.35529}};
```

If a symmetric threshold is known,

```
threshold = 1;

Map[If[Abs[#] > threshold, 0, #] &, data, {2}]

(* {{0.098952, 0.099761, 0, 0.18767, 0.06777, -0.20674, -0.14114, 
  0.091522, -0.040536, -0.37627, 0, -0.22996, -0.35529}} *)
```

Or for asymmetric thresholds

```
low = -3; hi = 4;

Map[If[low <= # <= hi, #, 0] &, data, {2}]

(* {{0.098952, 0.099761, 0, 0.18767, 0.06777, -0.20674, -0.14114, 
  0.091522, -0.040536, -0.37627, 0, -0.22996, -0.35529}} *)
```

If the thresholds must be determined on the fly, say within `n` standard deviations of the mean,

```
n = 1;

test[x_] := Module[
   {mu = Mean[x], s = StandardDeviation[x]}, 
   If[(mu - n*s) <= # <= (mu + n*s), #, 0] & /@ x];    

test /@ data


(* {{0.098952, 0.099761, 0, 0.18767, 0.06777, -0.20674, -0.14114, 
  0.091522, -0.040536, -0.37627, 0, -0.22996, -0.35529}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use three-argument form of [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) with `{0,0}` as the third argument:

> **Clip[$x$,{$min$,$max$},{$v_{min}$, $v_{max}$}]
>   gives $v_{min}$ for $x<min$ and $v_{max}$ for $x>max$**.

```
ClearAll[cliP]
cliP[d_, lo_, hi_] := Clip[d, {lo, hi}, {0, 0}]

data = {0.098952, 0.099761, 80, 0.18767, 0.06777, -0.20674, -0.14114,
 0.091522, -0.040536, -0.37627, -60, -0.22996, -0.35529};
cliP[data, -1, 1]
```

> {0.098952, 0.099761, 0, 0.18767, 0.06777, -0.20674, -0.14114, 
>     0.091522, -0.040536, -0.37627, 0, -0.22996, -0.35529}

```
ListLinePlot[{ data, cliP[data, -1, 1]},
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
 ClippingStyle -> Dashed, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[1], Blue, Thick, Dotted], 
   Directive[Opacity[.5], Red, Thick]} 
 PlotLegends -> {"data", "cliP[data, -1,1]"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using Clip, and then sending the clipped values to zero. For example, if the extreme values are +1 and -1:

```
Clip[data, {-1, 1}] /. {1 -> 0, -1 -> 0}
```